# Validation data in Laravel fails even it is true

Tags: laravel, validation

I need to validate data, but when I use Validation Form, it doesn't pass even if the test is true, my code below fails when I try to validate in the for loop, for the every single product. So I need to check if the user will put all the products before save data

```
public function store(Request $request)
   {
           $request->validate([
           'fature_number' => 'required',
           'date' => 'required',             
           'product_item'=>'required'
           ]);
           if($request->product_item !=0){
               for ($i = 1; $i <= $request->product_item; $i++)
               {
                   $this->validate($request,['product_id'=>'required']); // here is the fail         

                    ...
                    
                   }
               }
          ...
   }
```

[image]

Comment: sorry read that wrong; sure that might be the case but that input you are validating is a single input and does not need to be validated more than once, so not sure why you need to validate that single input more than once in a loop, if you could expand perhaps there is a different way to achieve your goal

Comment: lagbox, I added an image, so now i think is clearer, except the product item, I need to validate also every single product that I add to the table, because sometime user will forget to ad the product there

Comment: how are each of these inputs named?

Comment: product_id
...

<tr class="productItem"><td>' + i + '</td>' +
                    '<td><select class="form-control productSelect" name="product_id' + i +
                    '" id="product_id' + i + '"><option >Choose the product</option>' 
....

Comment: It is in the for loop, because it depends from product_item value

Comment: but you are never changing the variable name in your loop, you are always looking at `product_id` never `product_id1` or `product_id2`

Comment: I changed now, but when I try to save without a product, I have another error:
404
Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
I tried for test, so it should not to get me that error, but to display the required form